# Why is { a special character in Markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

I've noticed that I can escape curly braces. That is, if I type `\{`, I get {. Why are curly braces special characters; what Markdown syntax uses them? I couldn't find anything about it in [the editing-help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Because they are half of a free-hand circle.

Comment: obligatory +1 for mentioning free hand circles

Comment: All good standards have things that are *reserved for future use*

Comment: When one uses pandoc to add BibTeX citations to a Markdown document, it inserts some strings involving braces in a way that suggests pandoc expects Markdown to do something special with braces.  No idea what that something special is, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In at lease one extension to Markdown, something called [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/), braces are used to add an id to a header:

So in that variant of Markdown, this code:

```
## Header 2 ##      {#header2}
```

Will produce markup like:

```
<h2 id="header2">Header 2</h2>
```

I don't see any reference to extensibility on the [Markdown Documentation Page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), but perhaps the curly braces and other characters are reserved for future use.

Comment: I guess "reserved for future use" is the best answer I'm going to get. Though the existing symbols are plenty for extensibility; if they need a new bracket, they could use !( for example.

Answer (score 6):

It's just part of Markdown - Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:

```
\   backslash
`   backtick
*   asterisk
_   underscore
{}  curly braces
[]  square brackets
()  parentheses
#   hash mark
+   plus sign
-   minus sign (hyphen)
.   dot
!   exclamation mark
```

There's no mention of what special meaning `{` has anywhere on the [syntax page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) for Markdown though.

Answer (score 0):

The brace (`{}`) isn't special. But it don't do anything.

Not in this range: {0-9}.
Nor with this range:  {aardvark-zebra}

The backslash (`\`) just looks like it's helping out escape punctuation marks just in case things are done with them.

Special ed maybe.